# Why my expo terminal not opening ? (React-Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

When i was working on my windows pc , the expo terminal was opening at the browser automatically , now I'm working on my macOS and I cant reach there

Answer (score 0):

When you `expo start` wait until the app loads, then shake your device to bring up dev settings. After that, you'll see something like remote debugging. Tap that and it should bring up a new tab inside your browser.

Comment: "shake your device"!? I can't tell if you're making a bad joke or if this means something technical I don't get. Can you clarify? (I honestly don't know: I know some phones use shaking as a motion to do some things, but I can't fathom that applying here.)

Comment: Shaking the device has nothing to do with my issue , 
Im just trying to run my app on tunnel mode , because I cant open the app on my own device with the bar code for some reason .

Comment: I understand your confusion. Shaking the device when running a react-native app will bring up developer settings. Is what I wanted to say. If you cant open it with qr code, the issue might be related to your phone having an outdated sdk.